# ¿Porqué GitHub ha dejado de mostrar el contenido de mi readme.md en el perfil?

Tags: github

Estaba añadiendo unos cambios y todo estupendo. De repente me ha dejado de aparecer el contenido del readme en el profile. Lo he comprobado todo y está todo correcto, entras al readme del repo y se ve todo como debe.  Entras al perfil y no aparece, comienza en las contribuciones del último año y tal. El repo cumple los requisitos, he probado borrar el readme y volverlo a crear, he mirado todas las opciones y no sé porqué de repente ocurre esto. Mi perfil es Jorgeeerrl por si alguien quiere comprobarlo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Te fijaste si no estas usando un `.gitignore` en el proyecto al que corresponde tu repo??

el archivo `.gitignore` hace que git ignore tal archivo, x ende en tu repo de Github no va a aparecer

Comment: ¿`x` ende? Intenta no usar este tipo de redacción propio de las redes antisociales. Mejor usar el castellano completo. La redacción es muy importante, sobre todo a nivel peofesional.

Comment: A qué te refieres con redes antisociales?

Comment: Redes Antisociales: Meta (Facebook), X (Twitter), Instagram, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Pero esas no son redes "Antisociales" se denominan redes "Sociales"... digo, si me corriges al utilizar abreviaturas para palabras simples supongo que debería también corregirte las definiciones desacertadas para  términos..

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu respuesta. Era una cuestión de baneo. Al parecer hice un fork no permitido de un gist ¬¬ y me bloquearon el perfil sin notificación alguna.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).